# How to select elements dynamically generated with name attribute

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a php code for a forum page generating Reply buttons dynamically when a comment is posted like so:

```
<?php
        require("includes/conn.php");
        $stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT post_id, user, topic, post, time FROM post_tb ORDER BY time DESC");
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
            $num_of_rows = $result->num_rows;
            if ($num_of_rows > 0){
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                    $post_id = $row['post_id'];
                    $user = $row['user'];
                    $topic = $row['topic'];
                    $post = $row['post'];
                    $time = $row['time'];
                    $time = date('M dS, Y g:i A', strtotime($time));
                    echo '<div>
                            <div>
                                <h5><strong>'.$user.'</strong></h5><h6>'.$time.'</h6>
                                <h5><strong>'.ucfirst($topic).'</strong></h5>
                                <p data-id="'.$post_id.'">'.$post.'</p>
                            </div>      
                            <div>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rep" name="'.$post_id.'">Reply</button>
                            </div>
                            <form id="comment_reply" data-id="'.$post_id.'" method="post" >
                                <input type="text" class="hidden" value="'.$post_id.'" id="post_id">
                                <input type="text" class="hidden" value="'.$user.'" id="user">
                                <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="’.$post_id.'" "></textarea>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"  name = “'.$post_id.'” id="post_rep_sub">Submit</button>
                            </form>
                        <div/>';
                    }
                }
    ?>
```

Now I need to select the reply button with name attribute (for uniqueness since its dynamically generated) in event handling in jquery:

```
var postId = $('form input#post_id').val();
$(document).on('click', 'button[name="+postId+"]', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
alert(“worked!”);
```

I keep getting syntax uncaught error in console here.Someone please guide me. I know there’s something I’m doing wrong but cant figure out exactly.

Comment: Id's need to be unique - you are currently setting all to the same (post_id)

Comment: That looks a bit odd. I would think it should be like: `"button[name='"+postId+"']"`

Comment: @gavgrif thanks. But the id you are referring to is a hidden field to echo the id of the current comment that is in focus.

Comment: you also have a tick instead of a quote in one of the form elements

Comment: @Fred-ii-that has been fixed but its not the cause of the error.

Comment: @apokryfos thanks. using your edit i didnt get that error but no result either on console. Why is it not working?

Comment: Does the post_id start with a letter? Or is it numbers only? If the lather, you should change it since HTML id's can't start with a number.

Comment: @MysticEarth they are actually numbers, i used the id of the comment been replied to as the id's of the buttons.

Comment: In that case, prefix them with a `string`, ie "post-12345".

Comment: @banky: did you get it working?